# Converting Kelvin to Celsius in PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator

```
from qgis.analysis import  QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

raster = '/home/francis/QGIS/epelwrf/temp/temp0000-postwrf_d01_20180720_0600_f00000.gr2'
bohLayer = QgsRasterLayer(raster)
entries = [ raster ]

#Band
boh1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh1.ref = 'boh@1'
boh1.raster = bohLayer
boh1.bandNumber = 1
entries.append ( boh1 )

expression = '( ' + entries[0].ref + ' ) - 275.15 '
print expression

calc = QgsRasterCalculator( expression, "/home/francis/QGIS/tiffout/1.tif", 'GTiff', bohLayer.extent(), bohLayer.width(), bohLayer.height(), entries )

calc.processCalculation()
```

I'm stuck in my project. trying to convert this gr2 file (that contains tempsfc which is in kelvin) into Celsius.

Comment: Welcome to the GIS SE. Could you explain exactly what is happening? Is the tool not working / giving incorrect results / errors?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for responding.I'm new in using GIS software in general. The source code that I found here is just not working. And I can't find anything related to what I am doing. All I need is to find out how conversion of units is done in PyQgis using 1 band raster. (the gr2 file that I am using has only 1 band and it contains the parameter 'surface temperature' which is in kelvin) I just need to convert it into celsius

Comment: Are you wanting for an answer explicitly for use with PyQGIS, or QGIS in general?

Comment: just pyqgis will be preferable

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see in your question try this:

Open QGIS
Click the Raster Option in the Top menu buttons, it lies between Vector and Database

Choose the first option: Raster Calculator
In the Raster Bands select the Temperature Raster
Under Operators select the "-" and in the Expression type 275.15

Choose the output layer location and name, keep the Format as default values.

That should work.

Comment: Thank you. I've already done that. but here at work, they are requiring me to find a way thru the qgis console, to do what the raster calculator is intended for but using pyqgis.

Comment: Sure no problem, from the original question I didn't see you wanted to explicitly use PyQGIS. I will leave this answer here in case someone else needs it.